# Boolean algebra, logic expression minimization

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

$$(A\land \neg A)\lor((A \land B) \lor(A\land B\land \neg C ))$$
I'm trying to minimize this Boolean expression with boolean algebra but i cant minimize it completly can i get some help?

Comment: You should show how far you have gotten, otherwise it seems like you are asking people to do everything for you.  Don't make it seem like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify like the following:
$$P = (A\land \neg A)\lor((A \land B) \lor(A\land B\land \neg C ))$$ 
$$A\land \neg A = \bot \Rightarrow P = (A \land B) \lor(A\land B\land \neg C ) = D \lor (D\land \neg C), D = A\land B \Rightarrow P = D = A\land B$$

In the above $R  =D\lor(D\land \neg C) = D$ because if $D$ is true, so the $R$ is true, and if $D$ is false, so $R$ is false. Therefore, we can conclude that $R = D$.

Answer (score 1):

It can be simplified as follows:

\begin{array}{l}
& (A \land \neg A) \lor ((A \land B) \lor (A \land B \land \neg C)) & \text{ Given }\\
& F \lor ((A \land B) \lor (A \land B \land \neg C)) & \text{ Complement }\\
& (A \land B) \lor (A \land B \land \neg C) & \text{ Identity }\\
& (A \land B) \land (T \lor \neg C) & \text{ Distributive }\\
& (A \land B) \land T & \text{ Identity }\\
& A \land B & \text{ Identity }\\
\end{array}